# How to stop getting an undefined value when changing a select value using useState and useEffect

Tags: select, react-hooks, material-ui, undefined

I have the following code in my first component, where I fetch some data from which I need to pull an array of strings and send it as values to my Material UI select component:

```
const Logs = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState({})
const [usersList, setUsersList] = useState([])
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

 const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.request({
        method: "GET",
        baseURL: 'some url',
        url: `/logger`,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      setData(data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    ( async () => {
      await getData();
    })()
  }, []);

  const isEmpty = obj => Object.keys(obj).length === 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    if(isEmpty(data) === false) {
      setUsersList(data.userNames)
    }
console.log('Data', data) //{userNames: ['Admin', 'User1', 'User2']
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(usersList[0]) //setting the user to Admin
  })

  const handleUserChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setUser(value);
  };
return (
    <div>
      <CssBaseline />
       {<LogsSelect 
            labelId="logs-user-select-label"
            selectId="logs-user-select"
            handleChange={handleUserChange}
            value={user}
            list={usersList}
            label='User'
        />
        }
)
}
```

My select is defined as a separate (generic) component:

```
const LogsSelect = (labelId, selectId, handleChange, value, list, label) => {
return (
    <FormControl
    className={classes.form}
    style={{ minWidth: "140px"}}
  >
    <InputLabel id={labelId}>{label}</InputLabel>
    <Select
      className={classes.select}
      labelId={labelId}
      id={selectId}
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={value}
    >
      {value && list?.map((el, index) => (
        <MenuItem value={el} key={index}>
          {el}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
)}
```

I get the following error:
Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value `undefined` for the select component.
Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
The available values are "". This is happening when rendering the components. I haven't even managed to get my list of values as options in my select, and then try and change the value.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `defaultValue=""` to the `<Select />`

```js
...
<Select
 defaultValue=""
>
...
</Select>
...
```